# How do I render points on every vertex of my geometry in React with three.js and Three-React-fiber?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am wondering how to use the pointsmaterial and the points object from three-react-fiber. I have a custom geometry that I import from a .gltf file and I currently render it like this:

```
<mesh
    castShadow
    receiveShadow
    ref={grip}
    geometry={nodes.Circle002_1.geometry}
    material={wired}
  />
```

However, I am lost in how to create a pointsmaterial and attach it to the mesh instead of the wired material I use now. Can someone please explain how to do this in React?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, the answer was really easy.
I changed the `<mesh` tag to a `<points` tag,
and I made a material with the following constructor:

`const pMaterial = new PointsMaterial();`
then I set the points size with:

`pMaterial.size = 0.01`

and I changed the material prop in the `<points` tag to:

`material={pMaterial}`.

This draws points at every vertex intersection of a custom 3d geometry.